# How do I simplify this expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

How do I simplify:
$$d=\frac{-(x+\alpha x)^2+(y+\alpha y)^2+2+x^2-y^2-2}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 x^2+\alpha^2 y^2}}$$
If simplification *is* possible, it should be possible with elementary algebra, but I'm completely lost as to how to go about it.

---

What I've done so far:
$$d=\frac{-(x+\alpha x)^2+(y+\alpha y)^2+2+x^2-y^2-2}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 x^2+\alpha^2 y^2}}$$
$$=\frac{-(x+\alpha x)^2+(y+\alpha y)^2+x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 x^2+\alpha^2 y^2}}=\frac{-α^2 x^2 - 2 α x^2 + α^2 y^2 + 2 α y^2}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 x^2+\alpha^2 y^2}}$$
$$\implies d^2=\frac{(-α^2 x^2 - 2 α x^2 + α^2 y^2 + 2 α y^2 - 2)^2}{\alpha^2x^2+\alpha^2y^2}$$

Comment: All of these $x^2,y^2$ terms scream to me some sort of trigonometric substitution thing. Specifically $x = r\cdot cos\theta$ and $y = r \cdot sin\theta$ - but that would only make sense in the context of "polar" coordinates. Not sure if that's something you would know about, so it might not be what you're expected to do (if at all).

Comment: This is actually a part of a general solution to a differential equation. Given the particular context (the equation relates the derivative of a particular function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ to the Euclidean distance from the origin) a substitution of polar coordinates might make sense.

Comment: You seem to have an extra summand in your work. 

$=\frac{-(x+\alpha x)^2+(y+\alpha y)^2+x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 x^2+\alpha^2 y^2}}=\frac{-α^2 x^2 - 2 α x^2 + α^2 y^2 + 2 α y^2}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 x^2+\alpha^2 y^2}}$

From there you can continue by pulling an alpha out of the denominator and cancelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{-\alpha^2x^2+\alpha^2y^2-2\alpha x^2+2\alpha y^2}{\sqrt{\alpha^2x^2+\alpha^2y^2}}=\frac{\alpha^2(y^2-x^2)+2\alpha(y^2-x^2)}{\alpha\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$\frac{\alpha^2(y^2-x^2)}{\alpha\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{2\alpha(y^2-x^2)}{\alpha\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\alpha\frac{(y^2-x^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+2\frac{y^2-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Thanks: @Timmay & @David Diaz

Answer (score 2):

I believe your third equality is incorrect.  Numerator distribution won't lead to any terms with x and y to the first power.

Then when you squared d below, you also have additional squares added to a in denominator where there were none as well as a double square for the entire numerator and denominator - essentially you have d to the 4th power with a being squared on bottom where it wasn't in the initial equation.

$$d=\frac{-(x+\alpha x)^2+(y+\alpha y)^2+2+x^2-y^2-2}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 x^2+\alpha^2 y^2}}$$

$$=\frac{-x^2(1+\alpha)^2+y^2(1+\alpha)^2+x^2-y^2}{\sqrt{\alpha x^2+\alpha y^2}}=\frac{(y^2-x^2)(1+ 2\alpha + \alpha^2)+ x^2 - y^2}{\sqrt{\alpha^2} \sqrt{x^2+ y^2}}$$
$$ =\frac{(2\alpha+\alpha^2)(y^2-x^2)}{\alpha \sqrt{x^2+ y^2}}$$

Can continue from there perhaps, factor an alpha, square both sides if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't add as a comment to the above notes -- new account.

Comment: Thank you, I lost track of what I was doing somewhere in my scratch-work. I've corrected the mistakes, it should be fine now.

Comment: his original equation has $\sqrt{\alpha^2\dots}$ in the denominator

Comment: @DavidDiaz It didn't before he edited it.  I've changed mine to reflect his correction.

Thanks Alfred